# What preprocessor can I used to detect if QT is used to build my codes

Tags: qt, preprocessor, c-preprocessor

I am writing a library project in C, which may be built with or without QT. Is there any preprocessor directive (no extra headers are required) that can I use to distinguish whether QT is in use in the C code?

I would like to do somthing like:

```
#ifdef I_AM_QT
// some qt specific codes
#else
// some codes for other environments
#endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you set your own define that will indicate whether you build with or without Qt?

Comment: You can take alook at [these](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html) macros

Answer (score 12):

```
#ifdef QT_CORE_LIB
// some qt specific codes
#else
// some codes for other environments
#endif
```

Comment: The question states `... no extra headers are required... `. Can you use `QT_CORE_LIB` define without including a Qt header?

Comment: @vahancho, yes. At least, for Qt 5.12.4 I see that compiler being invoked with `-DQT_CORE_LIB` when project is built with CMake, so it's a global macro definition available to all source files.